# Salir de un socket, programa python

Tags: python, python-3.x

quería saber si podeís ayudarme. Estoy haciendo un pequeño chat entre cliente y servidor con Python. El cliente ejecutará el programa, el usuario por teclado tendŕa varias opciones, entre ellas está la de salir del programa, lo cual que cliente se desconectará del servidor. Lo que no sé muy bien es como hacer para que tanto el cliente como el servidor se desconecten.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
try:
    sys.exit(main())

except KeyboardInterrupt:

    pass
```

Lo he intentado con esto , pero no me funciona. No sé si es que no se debe hacer así. Espero que podías explicarme como desconectar el cliente del servidor en ambos roles. Muchas gracias. ;)

Answer (score 1):

En el cliente puedes programar una condición que detecte si el usuario ha tecleado cierta palabra especial para terminar, como `"QUIT"` y en ese caso que cierre el socket de datos y termine. Algo así:

```
entrada = input("> ")
if entrada.rstrip() == "QUIT":
    sock.close()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Esto causará que el socket (que asumo que es TCP) entre en su fase de negociación de fin de conexión. Los detalles del protocolo no son muy importantes, se enviará un paquete al servidor solicitando el cierre de la conexión, que será manejado automaticamente por el sistema operativo del servidor. Lo que te interesa saber es que la próxima vez que el servidor haga un `recv()` el operativo le entregará una cadena vacía, que es la forma de señalarle que el socket se ha cerrado.

Por tanto en el servidor deberías tener algo de este estilo:

```
while True:  # Bucle infinito de manejo de mensajes
   msg = sock.recv(5000)   # Tamaño arbitrario de lectura
   if msg == b"":
      break                # salir del bucle infinito
   # O procesar el mesaje, generar respuesta, etc.
   # y volver al bucle infinito

sock.close()
```

Es decir, una vez el servidor detecta que el cliente ha cerrado el socket, sale del bucle y cierra a su vez el socket (de datos, el servidor podrá tener otro socket de escucha en el que acepte más clientes).

Faltan detalles sobre la lógica de tu servidor, si admite a más de un cliente a la vez y cómo gestiona la concurrencia (hilos, `select()`, asyncio?) pero la parte por la que preguntas, la detección del fin de la comunicación y el cierre correcto del socket, se haría así.

**Nota** Si detienes el servidor o el cliente con Ctrl+C, eso también cierra los sockets, pero no lo hace ordenadamente. Si el socket se cierra antes en el lado servidor, el sistema operativo lo mantendrá en un estado `CLOSE-WAIT` durante unos minutos, durante los cuales no podrás abrir un nuevo socket que escuche en el mismo puerto.